# I have a button on my form that once clicked runs update sql to update loyalty points on a database, but its not updating

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-update

The code for the update SQL takes the value from the field in the database and adds it to the number of points in this transaction then is supposed to update the field. Any help on this would be appreciated

```
string strCon = Properties.Settings.Default.ConString;
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strCon);
            conn.Open();//database open

            string strSQl = "SELECT points from customer WHERE customerID = " + txtCustID.Text + "";

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQl, conn);

            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();//reader open
            string strOutput = "";

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                strOutput += reader["points"].ToString();
            }//end while loop



            int intcurrent = Convert.ToInt32(strOutput);
            int intNewTrans = Convert.ToInt32(lblPoints.Text);

            int intNewPoints = intcurrent + intNewTrans;

            string strSqlUpdate = "UPDATE customer SET points = " + intNewPoints + " WHERE customerID = " + txtCustID.Text + "";

            OleDbCommand cmdUpdate = new OleDbCommand(strSqlUpdate, conn);


            string strUpdateOutput = "";

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                strUpdateOutput += reader["points"].ToString(); 
            }//end while loop

            MessageBox.Show(strUpdateOutput);

            reader.Close();

            conn.Close();//database closed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are *not* executing your update command. Just use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery.aspx) like;

```
cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection, command and reader automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.